# How do I sign a POST request with a body using Clojure and clj-oauth?

Tags: oauth, clojure, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to communicate with the quickbooks online REST API, which uses OAuth 1:

I can construct arbitrary GET requests like this:

```
(require '[oauth.client :as oauth])
(require '[cheshire.core :refer :all])
(require '[clj-http.client :as client])

(def OAuth-Consumer-Key     "qyprdtoUhI8AjLxEQ9tucTJkSiklKn")
(def OAuth-Consumer-Secret  "*********************")

(def OAuth-Access-Token         "qyprdaXOWBph7MUnkqzRVruovEMlvgUH52Gup8kfinSgbnJL")
(def OAuth-Access-Token-Secret  "********************************" )


(def consumer (oauth/make-consumer OAuth-Consumer-Key
                                   OAuth-Consumer-Secret
                                   ""
                                   ""
                                   ""
                                   :hmac-sha1))


(def get-url "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145835981692/account/4")

(def get-user-params {})

(def get-credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                    OAuth-Access-Token
                                    OAuth-Access-Token-Secret
                                    :GET
                                    get-url
                                    get-user-params))

(client/get get-url {:query-params (merge get-credentials get-user-params) })
```

But I can't construct the POST requests. If I put the body in the user-params, then it seems that the authentication works, but the API refuses to accept the request, but if I don't, it doesn't authenticate in the first place.

```
(def post-body "<Customer xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\" domain=\"QBO\" sparse=\"false\">\n<CompanyName>Best Company</CompanyName>\n<DisplayName>Sir Jonhn Doe</DisplayName>\n<BillAddr>\n<Line1>123 Main Street</Line1>\n<City>Mountain View</City>\n<Country>USA</Country>\n<CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>\n<PostalCode>94042</PostalCode>\n</BillAddr>\n</Customer>")

(def post-user-params {:content-type "application/xml" :body post-body})

(def post-credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                     OAuth-Access-Token
                     OAuth-Access-Token-Secret 
                     :POST
                     "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145835981692/customer"
                     post-user-params))


(client/post "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145835981692/customer"
             {:query-params (merge post-user-params post-credentials)
              :body post-body})
```

This hand constructed version works fine though. (done with the Postman extension for Chrome).

```
(client/post "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145835981692/customer"
                   {:headers {:authorization "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"qyprdtoUhI8AjLxEQ9tucTJkSiklKn\",oauth_token=\"qyprdaXOWBph7MUnkqzRVruovEMlvgUH52Gup8kfinSgbnJL\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1470828646\",oauth_nonce=\"WXZu67\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"a66RFI8clxNIhv8M1YzzijDgE1A%3D\""
                              :content-type "application/xml",
                              :cache-control "no-cache",
                              :postman-token "0effd852-8271-7f66-f43d-6710443c5107"}
                    :body post-body})
```

Can anyone see what I should be doing to sign the request properly?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found that this incantation works. It appears that you don't actually need to sign the body. And the crucial change was to move the content-type into the post request and out of the signed bit.

I have no idea what is going on here!

```
(def post-url "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145835981692/customer")

(def post-body (str "<Customer xmlns=\"http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3\" domain=\"QBO\" sparse=\"false\">\n"
                    "<CompanyName>Company</CompanyName>\n"
                    "<DisplayName>Sir Jeaweaaan Doe</DisplayName>\n"
                    "<BillAddr>\n"
                    "<Line1>123 Main Street</Line1>\n"
                    "<City>Mountain View</City>\n"
                    "<Country>USA</Country>\n"
                    "<CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>\n"
                    "<PostalCode>94042</PostalCode>\n"
                    "</BillAddr>\n"
                    "</Customer>"))

(def post-user-params {
                       :cache-control "no-cache"
                       })

(def post-credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                     OAuth-Access-Token
                     OAuth-Access-Token-Secret 
                     :POST
                     post-url
                     post-user-params))


(que? (client/post post-url
                   {:query-params (merge post-user-params post-credentials)
                    :content-type "application/xml"
                    :body post-body
              }))
```